# OKHttp listening for connection status

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I need to implement progress indicator as it's common for many of mobile app (i.e old G+). Basic Idea is that this indicator should be enabled as soon as first request starts and should be stopped when connection is stopped. The "won't do it" method is to implement right calls in all of the communication methods, but just wonder if **is it possible to listen for connection opening and closing in some centralised way**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connections are pooled & shared, so it’s potentially difficult to assign a connection open to an individual call. Your best bet is to create an interceptor to observe request start & completion. There’s an example [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/Progress.java).